# Adding checkbox in between text description in react native

Tags: flexbox, styles, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a view where I display a Heading and details which I get from server as below.

[image]

Now, in the question description there is a tag `__CB__` which I need to replace with the checkbox, so, instead of that tag there will be a checkbox and rest of the text will continue as usual. I have separated the text based on tag and placed a checkbox in between but I haven't been able to align the view, either it gets arranged columnwise or if I try to arrange in row the text doesn't continue. Here is what I've tried.

> Try 1:

```
<ScrollView
            style={styles.scrollStyle}
            scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
            onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
          >
            <View style={styles.checkBoxTextContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.questionText}>{questionText1}</Text>
              <CheckBox
                style={styles.checkboxStyle}
                onClick={this.checkboxClick}
                isChecked={this.state.isChecked}
                checkedImage={<Image source={Images.checkBoxTick} />}
                unCheckedImage={<Image source={Images.checkBoxEmpty} />}
                // leftText={questionText1}
                // rightText={questionText2}
              />

               <Text style={styles.questionText}>{questionText2}</Text>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
Styles
checkBoxTextContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  checkBoxStyle: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20
  }
```

Result:
[image]

> Try 2:

```
<ScrollView
                style={styles.scrollStyle}
                scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
                onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
              >
                  <Text style={styles.questionText}>{questionText1}</Text>
                  <CheckBox
                    style={styles.checkboxStyle}
                    onClick={this.checkboxClick}
                    isChecked={this.state.isChecked}
                    checkedImage={<Image source={Images.checkBoxTick} />}
                    unCheckedImage={<Image source={Images.checkBoxEmpty} />}
                    // leftText={questionText1}
                    // rightText={questionText2}
                  />

                   <Text style={styles.questionText}>{questionText2}</Text>
              </ScrollView>
```

Result:

[image]

I need the checkbox to continue in between text like the tag in my original image. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is sample working code for your scenario.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
    cb: {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 2,
        borderColor: 'red',
        marginTop: 4,
        marginHorizontal: 3,
    }
})

const sampleData = [ 'Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet',
'CB', 
'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit.',  'Curabitur',
'CB',
' nunc', 'vel', 'scelerisque', 'tempus.', 'CB', 'Morbi', 'luc', 'abcd', 'xyzw'
]

const CheckBox = () => (
    <View style={styles.cb} />
)

export default class CheckText extends Component {
    renderData = (data) => {
        const views = data.map((item) => {
            if (item === 'CB') { return <CheckBox />}
            return (<Text>{item}</Text>)
        })
        return views
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {this.renderData(sampleData)}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And this is snapshot of output

[image: Simulator screenshot]

**Note**:

I have parsed the text into array of strings. This is the key logic here. The way you decide to tokenize your input text will affect the rendering of your component. When I tried long strings as token, `flexWrap: 'wrap'` didn't work properly. See this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8960) for more details. Tokenizing into single words may do the job.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap the Text and Checkbox into `<Text>` tag.
Please try below solution. It may help you.

```
        <ScrollView
            style={styles.scrollStyle}
            scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
            onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
          >
            <View style={{
                 width:'100%',
                 flexDirection: "row"
            }}>
              // wrap into text tag
              <Text>
              // add space after first text
              <Text style={styles.questionText}>{questionText1+" "}</Text>
              <CheckBox
                style={styles.checkboxStyle}
                onClick={this.checkboxClick}
                isChecked={this.state.isChecked}
                checkedImage={<Image source={Images.checkBoxTick} />}
                unCheckedImage={<Image source={Images.checkBoxEmpty} />}
              />
               // add space before second text
               <Text style={styles.questionText}>{" "+questionText2}</Text>
              </Text>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This gives an error saying nesting of <View> within <Text> is currently not supported. I'm using react native version 0.57.8

Comment: I have tested it in iOS and react-native version 0.55.3. I think nested views only support in iOS. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#nested-views-ios-only
let me check for another solution